# What is the correct way to check for False?

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-expression

Which is better? (and why?)

```
if somevalue == False:
```

or

```
if somevalue is False:
```

Does your answer change if `somevalue` is a string?

Comment: I would write `if not somevalue:` although for non boolean types it will behave differently: `if not "":` will run the code but `if "" == False:` will not.

Comment: You generally don't explicitly compare objects to `False`/`True` in Python. Just do `if somevalue:` or `if not somevalue:`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It rather depends on what `somevalue` can be: if `somevalue` could be anything you could check that it's a boolean and `not`:

```
if isinstance(somevalue, bool) and not somevalue
```

this doesn't rely on `False` being a singleton. If it always is a singleton you can also do:

```
if somevalue is False
```

---

**But** PEP8 of Python states you shouldn't care if it about the class and just use:

```
if not somevalue
```

this will evaluate if `somevalue` is "falsy". See [Python documentation on Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

PEP8 states:

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using == .

and gives these examples:

```
Yes:   if greeting:
No:    if greeting == True:
Worse: if greeting is True:
```

which translates in your case to:

```
Yes:   if not greeting:
No:    if greeting == False:
Worse: if greeting is False:
```

Keep in mind that each string is considered "truthy" except the empty string `''`.

Answer (score 3):

`is` is checking whether two objects are literally *the same object*. `==` is checking for equality.

If you want to check whether something is false, e.g. *zero*, opposite of `True`, do `if something == False`.

As mentioned in the comments, you can certainly do `if not something`, it may improve readability quite a bit, but it's the same as `if bool(something) == False`.

I prefer equality, because, to my mind, `True` and `False` should behave just like `1` and `0` in terms of being *true* or *false*. For example `("a" == "a") == False` evaluates to `False` just like `("a" == "a") == 0` does.

Comment: mm, `if not something`?

Comment: @vaultah, yes, but if the question's stated like: choose either `==` either `is`, it's better to use `==`

Comment: *but it's the same as `if something == False`*, no. It's the same as `if bool(something) == False`.

Comment: @vaultah, _It's the same as `if bool(something) == False`_, true, but it's just a verbose way to say `if something == False`

Comment: `'' == False` is False, but `bool('') == False` is True.

Comment: @vaultah, well, you're right

Comment: Using is with False/True relies on an implementation detail of CPython. None is guaranteed to be a singleton. True and False are not. So e.g. pypy which doesn't need the small-number-cache CPython has could break your code, or needs to add extra treatment for is True/False, slowing things down. Edit: misattributed vaultah

Comment: @deets: Are you sure about that? PEP 285 says: "The values False and True will be singletons, like None."

Comment: @MarkDickinson I was, but I stand corrected. Removing my answer.